# Cosmos DB client-side logging

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to log all Cosmos DB API requests when debugging, but I can't find anything that just sends it the `ILogger` interface. There is some documentation that works with ETL, but this is obsolete (Codeplex doesn't provide the tooling anymore). Especially when using LINQ it's good to know which query is actually being generated.

Comment: What version of Cosmos DB SDK you're using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.19. I have set the default LogLevel to `Trace`, but I don't get any logging from the HttpClient or Cosmos DB APIs. I do get DEBUG logging from ASP.NET core.